# Bloquear Formulario

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Tengo un formulario de inscripción de participante, cuando acaba de registrar a los participantes se muestra otra pantalla "detalle". 
Pero si le dan hacia atras nuevamente aparece el formulario y puede volver a registrar. Como hago para prohibir eso? no quiero bloquear el boton atras.
Hay algun código o helper en codeigniter para resolver este problema?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que quieres es que no pueda volver a atrás (o que vaya a otra página que no sea la de registrar).

Mírate documentación de javascript de [History](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/History) ([aquí hay ejemplos](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_go.asp)). Creo que es HTML5, pero no estoy seguro. Sé que no has puesto tag JavaScript, pero entiendo que debe haber algún equivalente en PHP.

Yo uso esto para evitar ir atrás:

```
/* Evita hacer "ATRAS" al navegador */
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    history.go(1);
};
```

Si quieres ir a una página concreta, cambia el `history.go(1)` por `history.go('URL')`.

Answer (score 1):

creo que lo mejor es que uses sesiones de php.
Así podrás saber si el usuario ha rellenado el formulario (o a iniciado sesión), y aunque pulse hacía atrás, puedes hacer que siga viendo la página detalle.

Aquí te dejo un código en php con un formulario y una página de detalle, usando sesiones para impedir que vuelva atrás al formulario. Puedes probarlo así o poner tu código del formulario y de la página detalle.

```
    <?php   
    // creo una sesion
    session_start();

    // si pulsa el enlace cerrar sesion
    // elimino las variables
    if (isset($_GET['cerrarsesion'])){
        unset( $_SESSION['nombre'] );
        unset($_POST['nombre']);
        unset($_POST['enviar']);
        unset($_GET['cerrarsesion']);
        header('Location: index.php');
    }


    // si el usuario rellena el formulario y lo envia
    if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
        // creo una variable de sesion con el nombre
        $_SESSION['nombre']=$_POST['nombre'];   
    }

    // si se ha creado la variable de sesion con el nombre
    // muestro la pagina de detalle
    if (isset($_SESSION['nombre'])){
?>

        <!-- pagina de detalle -->
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <?php
                    echo "Hola, " . $_SESSION['nombre'];
                ?>
                <p>Pagina de detalle</p>
                <a href="index.php?cerrarsesion=true" name="cerrarsesion">Cerrar Sesion</a>
            </body>
        </html>

<?php
    // si no ha pulsado enviar
    // muestro el formulario
    }else{
?>

    <!-- pagina de formulario -->
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="formulario" action="index.php" method="post">
                <input id="campo1" name="nombre" type="text" />
                <input id="campo3" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />           
            </form>
            </html>
<?php
} // ciero else
?>
```

Comment: Parece que el if

     `if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
            $_SESSION['nombre']=$_POST['nombre'];   
     }`        

Se puede agrupar justo con el siguiente if   

    `if (isset($_SESSION['nombre'])){ ...`     

Pero parece ser que si pulsas hacia atrás la variable $_POST['enviar'] sigue definida y con valor, mientras que no pasa esto con la variable $_SESSION['nombre'].

Comment: Si llegas a la página detalle varias veces, (usando el formulario y cerrando la sesión varias veces) puedes volver atrás y aparece el formulario con el nombre del anterior usuario.  Para solucionar esto puedes hacer una redirección a la misma página al cerrar la sesión.   Seguro que esta pregunta se la han hecho muchos, espero que den más respuestas y que opinen sobre esta.

Answer (score 1):

creo que la mejor opción en por el lado de las sesiones como dice Rubén Castro. en Codeigniter deberías crear la sesión en el controlador luego de insertar los datos.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('inscripto', 'si');
```

y en el controlador que carga la vista con el formulario de inscripción, verificar si la sesión está creada, y si está creada cargar otra vista con un mensaje estilo: usted ya se encuentra registrado.

```
$this->session->has_userdata('inscripto');
```

el usuario también puede cambiar de navegador... asi que deberías tambien verificar que los inserts sean unicos (por ejemplo que no permita email repetido, o numero de documento, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Al margen de las sesiones `PHP`que te ha comentado @Rubén castro, también puedes usar el evento `BLUR`o `CHANGE` de `JQUERY`, para comprobar si el dato rellenado esta ya guardado en la base de datos.

En caso de tenerlo guardado, retornas un valor de error y se lo muestras al usuario por pantalla

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión, creo que no es buena práctica hacer la validación con sesiones. Ese tipo de formulario lo he programado antes, lo que yo uso es una simple función de validación de datos.

Por ejemplo, si son dos formularios y los datos se guardan en una misma base de datos, tienes que crear una función en un controlador, donde recoge los datos del primer formulario. Esos datos cuando los llenen en la vista y los envíe al controlador, simplemente haces una validación donde compruebas mediante una función de form_validation que te haga una petición al modelo y busque en la base de datos si existe el correo o nombre de usuario, o algún dato que pueda ser único en el primer formulario. Si no existe entonces guardas ese envío en la base de datos y redireccionas al segundo formulario donde muestras un mensaje de success, o en caso de que existan los datos en el envío entonces redireccionas al segundo formulario y muestras un mensaje donde digas que ya esos datos existían o algo así. Y en el segundo formulario sólo tienes que hacer cuando envíe los datos al controlador que se modifique la fila de la tabla en la base de datos y le agregas los datos que falten.